# Grab string values from dict and make new list

Tags: python

I have a dict that contains site location names and key codes
i'm trying to pull the site location names (which are values) out of the dict and make a simple list.

I have this code which prints exactly what i want:

```
for s in mydict['mykey']:
    print(s['site'])

site1
site2
site3
site4
```

but when i try to do something like this:

```
for s in mydict['mykey']:
     mylist = list(s['site'])
```

or

```
for s in mydict['mykey']:
     mylist2 = (s['site'])
```

i only get the last value:

```
mylist
['s', 'i', 't', 'e', '4']

mylist2
'site4'
```

Basically just looking to have the sites in a list, one per line

Comment: Instead of using `list(s['site'])` use `mylist.append(s['site`])`  and of course you need to initialize `mylist = []` before the loop.

Comment: Just append the ouput to a list?

Comment: Append the output into the list you are overwriting into a list which is converting string into list.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension:

```
mylist = [s['site'] for s in mydict['mykey']]
```

This is the equivalent of:

```
mylist = []
for s in mydict['mykey']:
    mylist.append(s['site'])
```