# Need to filter list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have one large list of dictionaries pulled from a database. I'm wondering if there is a way to search the first list of dicts to only show the first 3 digits (list would be unique to avoid duplicate entries) in one dropdown menu and, based on the selection, show the appropriate options?

Essentially the first dropdown would show selectable options "220, 221, 222, 223, 224", let's say we selected "220", then the second dropdown would show '220_2_INTL_PRSTR_ET_619076', '220_4_KAL_T2E_DOLE_344657'. I'm not worried about the code needed to create the dropdowns, just the filtering of the list of dicts to achieve the results.

```
list_of_dict = [ 
{'label': '220_2_INTL_PRSTR_ET_619076', 'value': '220_2_INTL_PRSTR_ET_619076'}, 
{'label': '220_4_KAL_T2E_DOLE_344657', 'value': '220_4_KAL_T2E_DOLE_344657'}, 
{'label': '221_1_PB_520_REF_174049', 'value': '221_1_PB_520_REF_174049'},
{'label': '222_5_KAL_T2E_YT_344991', 'value': '222_5_KAL_T2E_YT_344991'}, 
{'label': '223_2_PB_520_REF_174050', 'value': '223_2_PB_520_REF_174050'}, , 
{'label': '224_3_PB_520_REF_174051', 'value': '224_3_PB_520_REF_174051'}]
```

Comment: You need to grab the part of the dictionary you need and then turn that part into a list and grab the parts you need. Look at this code to figure out how to do this: [Grab string values from dict and make new list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57501020/grab-string-values-from-dict-and-make-new-list?adlt=strict&toWww=1&redig=369983E833624BE0A0D95C471905341B).

Comment: What have _you tried_, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward to turn your list into a dictionary that has exactly what you need:

```
list_of_dict = [
    {'label': '220_2_INTL_PRSTR_ET_619076', 'value': '220_2_INTL_PRSTR_ET_619076'},
    {'label': '220_4_KAL_T2E_DOLE_344657', 'value': '220_4_KAL_T2E_DOLE_344657'},
    {'label': '221_1_PB_520_REF_174049', 'value': '221_1_PB_520_REF_174049'},
    {'label': '222_5_KAL_T2E_YT_344991', 'value': '222_5_KAL_T2E_YT_344991'},
    {'label': '223_2_PB_520_REF_174050', 'value': '223_2_PB_520_REF_174050'},
    {'label': '224_3_PB_520_REF_174051', 'value': '224_3_PB_520_REF_174051'}
]

# it's a "one-liner", a dict comprehension split over a few lines for readability:
result = {
    p: [d for d in list_of_dict if d['label'].startswith(p)]
    for p in set(d['label'][:3] for d in list_of_dict)
}

print(result['220'])  # the contents for this prefix
print(result.keys())  # the keys for your first dropdown
```

Output:

```
[{'label': '220_2_INTL_PRSTR_ET_619076', 'value': '220_2_INTL_PRSTR_ET_619076'}, {'label': '220_4_KAL_T2E_DOLE_344657', 'value': '220_4_KAL_T2E_DOLE_344657'}]
['222', '220', '224', '223', '221']
```

Note that the keys are out of order, but sorting is straightforward.

Instead of `d['label'][:3]` you could consider `d['label'].split('_')[0]`, if the prefixes aren't all 3 characters long, but instead are "everything before the first underscore".

Edit: in the comments, you asked for some additional explanation of the core bit of code:

```
{
    p: [d for d in list_of_dict if d['label'].startswith(p)]
    for p in set(d['label'][:3] for d in list_of_dict)
}
```

- Anything of the form `{..: .. for .. in ..}` is a dictionary comprehension, constructing a dictionary using a very efficient loop.
- Here it's `{p: ... for p in set(d['label'][:3] for d in list_of_dict)}`. So, p loops over the elements of `set(d['label'][:3] for d in list_of_dict)` and for every `p`, a key is added to the dictionary.
- That `d['label'][:3] for d in list_of_dict` is a generator expression that generates the first three characters (`[:3]`) of every `'label'` value for every dictionary `d` in your `list_of_dict`. I.e. `['220', '220', '221', '222', etc.]`. And the `set()` around it reduces it to have only unique elements.
- The value part of the dictionary comprehension is a list comprehension, so a list is construction as a value for each key `p`. A list comprehension looks like `[.. for .. in ..]` (with an optional `if ..`-part to filter the contents)
- The comprehension `[d for d in list_of_dict if d['label'].startswith(p)]` takes each dictionary `d` from your `list_of_dict`, but only keeps it in the resulting list if `d['label'].startswith(p)` is `True` (i.e. only if `d['label']` starts with `p`, which is the current 3-letter string being used as a key.

So, it gathers all of the 3-letter prefixes in a set, and then generates a dictionary with those unique prefixes as keys, and a list of all the dictionaries that have `'label'` values starting with the matching 3-letter prefix, as their value.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get it to work! Can you help me understand what 
p: [d for d in list_of_dict if d['label'].startswith(p)]
    for p in set(d['label'][:3] for d in list_of_dict)

Comment: I've added an explanation - if there's words in there you're not familiar with and my explanation isn't enough (like 'list comprehension' or 'generator'), you should probably look up a guid or tutorial on the subject. They are very useful parts of the Python language to master, you'll end up using them a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Given a prefix, the filtering code comes down to an if-statement and a [str.startwith()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) test:

```
prefix = '220'
for d in list_of_dict:
    if d['label'].startswith(prefix):
        print(d)
```

For purposes of a dropdown menu, it may be preferable to group the data in advance using [defaultdict()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and extracting the prefix with slicing:

```
from collections import defaultdict

grouped = defaultdict(list)
for d in list_of_dict:
    prefix = d['label'][:3]
    grouped[prefix].append( d['value'])
```

Now you can lookup results directly:

```
>>> grouped['220']
['220_2_INTL_PRSTR_ET_619076', '220_4_KAL_T2E_DOLE_344657']
```

This strategy is also faster than filtering the entire list for every lookup.

Answer (score 0):

As first step, you can use `set()` to obtain the first tree characters from labels without duplicates.

Then you can create a function to filter the list using `str.startswith`:

```py
def get_options(l):
    return {d["label"][:3] for d in l}


def filter_list(l, s):
    return [d for d in l if d["label"].startswith(s)]


print(get_options(list_of_dict))
print(filter_list(list_of_dict, "220"))
```

Prints:

```
{"222", "221", "224", "220", "223"}
[
    {
        "label": "220_2_INTL_PRSTR_ET_619076",
        "value": "220_2_INTL_PRSTR_ET_619076",
    },
    {
        "label": "220_4_KAL_T2E_DOLE_344657",
        "value": "220_4_KAL_T2E_DOLE_344657",
    },
]
```